# How do I get /_layout/15/event.aspx to show a single instance of a recurring event on SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp, recurring-events

Using pnp/sp we are able to get the list of events including the recurring ones expanded but when we click on the details url we want it to go to the single instance of event with this layout /_layout/15/event.aspx.  We have tried to use the instance id, recurrence id, and the unique id but all do not work.

Here is the code to get the list and display the items and were we set the url for the details page:

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any */

/**

 * ExtensionService

 */




import { ICalendarService } from "..";

import { BaseCalendarService } from "../BaseCalendarService";

import { ICalendarEvent } from "../ICalendarEvent";

import { Web, sp } from "@pnp/sp";




export class SharePointCalendarService extends BaseCalendarService

  implements ICalendarService {

  constructor() {

    super();

    this.Name = "SharePoint";

  }




  public getEvents = async (): Promise<ICalendarEvent[]> => {

    const parameterizedFeedUrl: string = this.replaceTokens(

      this.FeedUrl,

      this.EventRange

    );




    // Get the URL

    const webUrl = parameterizedFeedUrl.toLowerCase();




    // Break the URL into parts

    const urlParts = webUrl.split("/");




    // Get the web root

    const webRoot = urlParts[0] + "/" + urlParts[1] + "/" + urlParts[2];




    // Get the list URL

    const listUrl = webUrl.substring(webRoot.length);




    // Find the "lists" portion of the URL to get the site URL

    const webLocation = listUrl.substr(0, listUrl.indexOf("lists/"));

    const siteUrl = webRoot + webLocation;




    // Open the web associated to the site

    const web = new Web(siteUrl);




    // Get the web

    await web.get();

    // Build a filter so that we don't retrieve every single thing unless necesssary

    try {

      const list = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Events").select("SchemaXml").get();

      const schemaXml = list.SchemaXml;

      const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(schemaXml, "text/xml");

      const fields = doc.getElementsByTagName("Field");

      const viewFields = Array.from(fields).map((field) => {

        const name = field.getAttribute("Name");

        return `<FieldRef Name="${name}"/>`;

      }).join("\n");

      const listId = await web.getList(listUrl).select("Id").get();

      const items = await web.getList(listUrl)

        .renderListDataAsStream({

          ViewXml: `<View Type="CALENDAR" RecurrenceRowset="TRUE" ContentTypeID="0x">

        <Query>

          <Where>

            <DateRangesOverlap>

              <FieldRef Name="EventDate"/>

              <FieldRef Name="EndDate"/>

              <Value Type="DateTime">

                <Now/>

              </Value>

            </DateRangesOverlap>

          </Where>

        </Query>

        <ViewFields>

          ${viewFields}

        </ViewFields>

        <ViewData>

          <FieldRef Name="Title" Type="CalendarMonthTitle"/>

          <FieldRef Name="Title" Type="CalendarWeekTitle"/>

          <FieldRef Name="Location" Type="CalendarWeekLocation"/>

          <FieldRef Name="Title" Type="CalendarDayTitle"/>

          <FieldRef Name="Location" Type="CalendarDayLocation"/>

        </ViewData>

        <RowLimit>10</RowLimit>

      </View>`

        });




      console.log(items);

      // Once we get the list, convert to calendar events

      const events: ICalendarEvent[] = items.Row.map((item: any) => {

        const url = `${window.location.origin}/_layouts/15/Event.aspx?ListGuid=${listId.Id}&ItemId=${item.MetaInfo[0].lookupId}&UniqueId=${item.UniqueId}`;

        const eventItem: ICalendarEvent = {

          title: item.Title,

          start: item.EventDate,

          end: item.EndDate,

          url: url,

          allDay: item.fAllDayEvent,

          category: item.Category,

          description: item.Description,

          location: item.Location

        };

        return eventItem;

      });

      // Return the calendar items

      return events;

    }

    catch (error) {

      console.log("Exception caught by catch in SharePoint provider", error);

      throw error;

    }

  }

}
```

It does go to the detail page and flicker with the right information for a second but then gives us the parent information.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thank you!